# How to get the line number of a warning that made by pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, warnings

**Edited:**

I have some codes written in `Python` and used pandas to make and manipulate some DataFrames. In a few of them, I get some warnings. for example settingwithcopywarning or performancewarning. I want to catch the **lineno** that warning has happened and for that, I wrote the following code. I catch everything except lineno.

```
scripts = ['myfile.py', 'myotherfile.py']
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("default")
    for s in scripts:
        with open(s) as f:
            try:
                exec(f.read())
            except Exception as e:
                print('An Error happend during the execution', e)
                raise
            finally:    
                f.close()    

    print(color.orange('There are {} error/s happend in {}.'.format(len(w), s)))
    for i in range(0, len(w)):
        print(color.green('LineNo: '), w[i].lineno)
        print(color.green('Line: '), w[i].line)
        print(color.green('warning category: '), w[i].category.__name__)
        print(color.green('Warning: '), w[i].message) 
        print(color.green('filename: '), w[i].file) 
        print(color.cyan('-' * 40))
```

for `w[i].lineno` I expect the **line number**.

The number that I am getting does not belong to the original file. it belongs to python core modules. I get something like 5312. 
how can I trace back the lineno to my own script?

Answer (score 1):

The [warnings module uses `linecache`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/warnings.py#L41) to look up the source code line when `msg.line` is missing.

```
if msg.line is None:
    try:
        import linecache
        line = linecache.getline(msg.filename, msg.lineno)
        ...
```

You could do the same thing:

```
import warnings
import linecache
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("default")

    # trigger a SettingWithCopyWarning
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
    subdf = df.iloc[::2]
    subdf.loc[:, 'A'] = 99

    for wi in w:
        if wi.line is None:
            wi.line = linecache.getline(wi.filename, wi.lineno)
        print('line number {}:'.format(wi.lineno)) 
        print('line: {}'.format(wi.line))
```

prints

```
line number 633:
line:                     self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
```

Comment: @ubuntu Thank you for the answer, yes, it prints "self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value", so, how from that I can get the line number? :) I mean is there any way to do so?

Comment: `wi.lineno` is the line number. I don't believe that attribute is ever missing (at least not when the source code is written in Python). `wi.line` is the source code on the line that raised the warning. That is the attribute which is sometimes `None`.

Comment: your answer was correct about the line. what I was hoping to get is lineno. my bad. :|